# honestech TVR2.5 screen appearing white, no audio

Tags: drivers, video, tv, video-capture, windows-10-v1809

[image: screenshot]

honestech TVR 2.5 capturing video using techcom tv tuner ssd-tv-817_125_win7_support from SOLID HD S2 6024 set top box for Indian DoorDarshan Free Dish on W10-64 bit, Composite channel, no compatibility setting.

honestech is appearing in programfiles(x86) so I guess it is 32 bit version,
driver install files has both 32-64 bit that is also appearing in programfiles(x86) so that is also 32 bit.

Only video is captured, audio I have directly put on separate set of USB speakers connected to set top box.

It was working on earlier windows and first install of w10 from pen drive.

Then it updated to 1803 and it worked and then stopped at a time so I have to do a system restore and it started working again.

Then it updated to 1809 and it said "no driver". I reinstalled tv tuner driver, it started working for an hour or so. Stopped and is not working since then. I don't have any 1809 restore point during its working time to restore to. Screen Showing totally white.

The point is:
Chris TV is working in this w10 also and showing video. so rest of the software/ driver are also working.

The same pc has video appearing even now in w8.1-64 bit both in christv as well as in this honestechTVR2.5. So I guess hardware/ connections is ok.

I tried to update driver of Tv tuner in device manager, windows searches and finds a driver of CINERGY Mini Stick but says, "driver is found but not able to install", no error number or message what prevented it from installing.

while installing it, it installs VC++ 2008 x86 9.0.90729.17, windows has automatically downloaded and installed both x86 and x64 versions of 9.0.90729.17 and also of 9.0.90729.6161, if that can give some clue.

Searched all over the net, not finding any answer that worked. Please resolve.

Thanks.